# Admob implementation for Android

Tags: android, admob

I want to implement admob ads on my apps, but I didn't find any good resources to reference it. 
I went to http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html but It only give me the implementation for testing device. How about to I want to see my apps show real ads.

**Edit :** I have my account at Admob, and had downloaded the SDK, but there's no real ads example there.
So please don't suggest me to register or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for test ads and live ads are virtually the same.  The only lines you should add/remove to get test/live ads are:

```
AdRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
AdRequest.addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE");
```

The first line will give you test ads on the emulator, the second would give you test ads on a specific device, provided you put in the correct device id, which you could get from the logcat output.  If these lines are removed from the code, live ads will be served.

Note it is good practice to use test ads during development.

Answer (score 0):

You go to [Admob website register](http://www.admob.com/)

Then add a new add campaign to show adds in your app.

Wait for admob to approve it, and start showing adds.

Everything you need you can learn by googling tutorials about how to use it.

Here is a good place to start.

[Abmob for beginners](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307223&topic=1307220&ctx=topic)

Comment: I have my own account at Admob and have implemented webapps Banner. I have 3 apps there. Maybe you not downloaded the latest Admob Android SDK, if you downloaded it, you'll know what I mean.